# Telegram-desktop snap package doesn't run after reboot

Tags: apt, package-management, snap, telegram

please, I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and I'm very satisfied yet. But unfortunatelly, Telegram desktop stops work after today's reboot. I really don't know why because it was works correctly before today.

If I'm trying start telegram from command line I have this error message:

```
~$ telegram-desktop 
QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display :1
Telegram[0x9338cf]
Telegram[0x933e4c]
Telegram(_ZN15google_breakpad16ExceptionHandler12GenerateDumpEPNS0_12CrashContextE+0x382)[0x11d0d0c]
Telegram(_ZN15google_breakpad16ExceptionHandler12HandleSignalEiP9siginfo_tPv+0x1c3)[0x11d08e7]
Telegram(_ZN15google_breakpad16ExceptionHandler13SignalHandlerEiP9siginfo_tPv+0x1ab)[0x11d05ff]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x11390)[0x7f9195a16390]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(gsignal+0x38)[0x7f9195151428]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(abort+0x16a)[0x7f919515302a]
Telegram[0x1f55117]
Telegram(_ZN14QXcbConnectionC2EP19QXcbNativeInterfacebjPKc+0xe93)[0x1624423]
Telegram(_ZN15QXcbIntegrationC1ERK11QStringListRiPPc+0x2ea)[0x15f907a]
Telegram[0x15f7c4b]
Telegram[0x1e1bc1d]
Telegram[0x1b38bad]
Telegram[0x1b397b5]
Telegram[0x2128295]
Telegram[0x1b3ad8f]
Telegram[0x17f8889]
Telegram(_ZN11ApplicationC2EN3gsl8not_nullIPN4Core8LauncherEEERiPPc+0x3a)[0xfcc76a]
Telegram(_ZN4Core8Launcher18executeApplicationEv+0x3e)[0x93088e]
Telegram(_ZN4Core8Launcher4execEv+0x54)[0x930d14]
Telegram(main+0x32)[0x78a2a2]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf0)[0x7f919513c830]
Telegram(_start+0x29)[0x79b569]
Aborted (core dumped)
```

In fact, I had many probles with snap packages like with gnome-calculator or gnome-system-monitor. This applications was delivered as snap packages after normal install. But I don't think that this applications need to be as snap. After uninstall and install as normal app works correct.

But Telegram I cannot install as normal application via `sudo apt install` because it is not in stadard ppa repository :( Only I can download **AppImage** from official Telegram website. But then snap is just a crap of ... (you know) and I recommend migrate to Flatpak.

Please, can you help where can be a problem with snap package of this application?

My Snap applications:

```
$ ls -la /snap/
total 40
drwxr-xr-x  9 root root 4096 máj 20 20:16 .
drwxr-xr-x 24 root root 4096 máj 19 22:39 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 máj 20 20:16 bin
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root 4096 máj  7 19:04 core
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root 4096 máj  9 20:28 gnome-3-26-1604
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root 4096 máj  5 20:54 gnome-characters
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root 4096 máj  5 20:54 gnome-logs
-r--r--r--  1 root root  548 máj  5 14:08 README
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 máj  6 09:09 telegram-desktop
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 máj 20 20:02 vlc
```

**vlc** works correctly yet :) Thanks for any advice

PS: I tried refresh snap package via `snap refresh` but it doesn't helps

```
sudo snap refresh telegram-desktop
snap "telegram-desktop" has no updates available
```

Thanks for reply

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This problem affects me too. The first time I connected required snap interfaces to telegram, and it worked. But today the problem showed up itself again. I fix it by remove and install again telegram with:

```
sudo snap remove telegram-desktop
sudo snap install telegram-desktop
```

Note that by now exists a telegram-desktop package within default ppa and you can install it by

```
sudo apt install telegram-desktop
```

Comment: Yes, great. Thanks. My solution was replace telegram from `snap` package into `flatpak`

Comment: snap remove/snap install worked for me in bionic

Comment: `snap` package does not work for me from the first time I've tried it on 18.04.4 LTS. However `apt` works fine

Comment: is it installed on your system ?

Answer (score -1):

Frist remove the packge.

```
sudo snap remove telegram-desktop
```

Install it back.

```
sudo snap install telegram-desktop
```

Now perform another install using the default package manager.

**For Debian based OS,**

```
sudo apt install telegram-desktop
```

**For Arch based OS,**

```
sudo pacman -S telegram-desktop
```

*Extend @Bob91 answer for Arch users.*